# Retirar dados de um array e inserir na table

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Eu incluo em um `array`, dados informados pelo usuário. Mas, eu utilizo somente um `array` para armazenar dados de dois campos, onde eu uso **"P"**(E os dados digitados) para o primeiro campo e **"S"**(E os dados digitados) para o segundo campo. Assim os dados ficam fora de ordem no `array`. Exemplo:

```
array_dados=[P01000213, P154878946, S797465464,P454464654,S48897874, ...]
```

Assim, eu gostaria de armazenar na `table do banco` as informações do `array` .. Mas, **"P"** e **"S"** são campos diferentes na `table` e eu só utilizo as letras antes dos números para saber para quais campos eles irão!

Minha dúvida ... "Como retirar essas letras (**P** e **S**) e armazenar os dados em seus devidos campos na tabela?"

Tabela que preciso armazenar os campos:

```
CREATE TABLE sai_info_dados
(
  seq_info integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sam_cad_info'::regclass),
  tx_num_prim character varying(12) NOT NULL,
  tx_num_secu character varying(15) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Porque você não facilita o seu trabalho e cria o array multidimensional? Tipo isso: `$array_dados = array(array('P' => '01000213', 'S' => ''),array('P' => '154878946', 'S' => '797465464'),array('P' => '454464654', 'S' => '48897874'));` assim você garante a paridade dos dados.

Answer (score 2):

Para separar os ítens, você pode fazer algo assim:

```
$tabela_p = array();
$tabela_s = array();

for each ( $array_dados as $item ) {
   if( strtoupper( $item{0} ) == 'P' ) {
       $tabela_p[] = substr( $item, 1 );
   } else {
       $tabela_s[] = substr( $item, 1 );
   }
}
```

Após esse *loop*, você terá duas arrays separadas com os respectivos ítens, e sem as letras.

Como você não postou o critério de inserção desejado, seguem algumas possibilidades:

- Você pode usar um `foreach` em cada uma das `$tabela`s;
- você pode trocar a inserção nos arrays pelos respectivos `INSERT`s;
- Caso o resultado seja simétrico, (um P para cada S), você pode inserir na mesma linha da tabela com um loop:

  ```
  for( $i = 0; $i < count( $tabela_p ); $i ++ ) {
     // 'INSERT INTO ... VALUES( '.$tabela_a[$i].', '.$tabela_s[$i].' )'
  }
  ```

  (ajuste conforme o caso real)

Comment: @ Bacco muito obrigado pela informação! sua explicação me ajudou na base de poder fazer separar os campos para a inserção!

Answer (score 2):

Use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) para remover o primeiro caracter de `$item` dessa forma você pega o valor 'limpo' para gravar no banco(`$valor`). Depois para verificar em qual campo deve ser gravado pode usar `$item[0]` que pega o primeiro caracter.

```
<?php

$arr = array('P01000213', 'P154878946', 'S797465464','P454464654','S48897874');

foreach($arr as $item){
    $valor = substr($item, 1);

    if($item[0] == 'S'){
        echo 'INSERT INTO tabela (s_campo) .... '. $valor  .'<br>';
    }else if($item[0] == 'P'){
        echo 'INSERT INTO tabela (p_campo) ....'. $valor .'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela informação, eu tinha conhecimento do substr(), mas não sabia como utilizar corretamente!